# How do I get this to work 3.2 ”TFT 480x320?

Tags: stm32, tft

[image]Help please. I am using STM32F401CCU board to connect to 3.2 ”TFT 480x320. I can't get it to work, the display just glows white and nothing happens.

[http://imgs.elgrad.net/Upload/sub-4/21450.pdf][2](http://imgs.elgrad.net/Upload/sub-4/21450.pdf)

Main.c  ***************************************************************

#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "SPI.h"

int main(void)
{

```
SystemInit();

SPI_init();

while(1)
{
    SPI1_Write(0x34);
}
```

}

SPI.c ********************************************************************

#include "stm32f4xx.h"

#include "SPI.h"

void SPI_init(){

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;// Включаем тактирование портов А
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;// Включаем тактирование SPI 1
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1 | 
GPIO_MODER_MODER4_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER3_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER2_0;
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (5<<20);// AF7 на ноге CLK  - PA5
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (5<<24);// AF7 на ноге MISO - PA6
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (5<<28);// AF7 на ноге MOSI - PA7

GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR_2;//RS
GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR_3;//CS
GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR_4;//RESET


SPI1->CR1 |=  SPI_CR1_BR_2;// Скорость передачи fPCLK/32
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_DFF;// Выбор размера передаваемых данных 8 бит
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SSM;
SPI1->CR1 |=  SPI_CR1_MSTR;
SPI1->CR1 &=  ~SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST;
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BIDIMODE;

SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_CPOL;
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_CPHA;

SPI1->CR1 |=  SPI_CR1_SPE;
```

}

void SPI1_Write(uint16_t data){

while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));

SPI1->DR = data;

}

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You don't say which display it is, which controller it uses, you are not driving any of the reset/chipselect/registerselect lines in any meaningful way, and are constantly sending 0x34 over SPI which the display ignores.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it? I'm stuck on this and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: HX8357B  such a controller on the display

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet of the display says it has a 16-bit parallel interface.

There is no way the display can be used via SPI interface.

Comment: I understand. Thank you